# Meteor pricing table issue

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

So I'm building a pricing table for mdl and I'm trying to populate the different plan options using templating and I'm having issues displaying the features section of the plans.  it looks like:

[image]

Here's a codepen of what I want it to look like: http://codepen.io/sylverfyst/pen/QyVYmK

Can someone give me an idea of where I've gone wrong with the blaze PlansRowOne and PlansRowTwo objects in my Javascript?  I think it might be the nested features: [], but I don't know what the actual syntax for it would be.

Here's What I've tried so far:

Outer HTML

```
<template name="sell">
  <div>
  <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col"><h1>CHOOSE A PLAN TO JOIN TODAY</h1></div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col"></div><!-- Spacer -->
      {{#each PlansRowOne}}
          {{> pricingItem}} 
      {{/each}}
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col"></div><!-- Spacer -->
      {{#each PlansRowTwo}}
          {{> pricingItem}} 
      {{/each}}
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col"></div><!-- Spacer -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Javascript File

```
Template.sell.helpers({
  PlansRowOne: [
    {title: "Basic 6 Month", Dollars: "$44.", Cents: "95", term: "/6 Months", Features: [{feature: "1 Listing for your Business"}, {feature: "Searchable Listing"}, {feature: "Ads on Listing"}, {feature: "Upload Photos"}, {feature: "Unlimited Categories"}, {feature: "X"}]},
    {title: "Basic 3 Month", Dollars: "$64.", Cents: "95", term: "/3 Months", Features: [{feature: "1 Listing for your Business"}, {feature: "Searchable Listing"}, {feature: "Ads on Listing"}, {feature: "Upload Photos"}, {feature: "Unlimited Categories"}, {feature: "X"}]},
    {title: "Showcase 6 Month", Dollars: "$64.", Cents: "95", term: "/6 Months", Features: [{feature: "1 Listing for your Business"}, {feature: "Searchable Listing"}, {feature: "Ads on Listing"}, {feature: "Upload Photos"}, {feature: "Unlimited Categories"}, {feature: "1st in Search Listings"}]},
  ],
  PlansRowTwo: [
    {title: "Professional Silver", Dollars: "$74.", Cents: "95", term: "/Month", Features: [{feature: "One Time Set Up Fee of $29.95"}, {feature: "10 Searchable Listings"}, {feature: "Ads on Listings"}, {feature: "Upload Photos"}, {feature: "Unlimited Categories"}, {feature: "X"}]},
    {title: "Professional Gold", Dollars: "$94.", Cents: "95", term: "/Month", Features: [{feature: "One Time Set Up Fee of $29.95"}, {feature: "10 Searchable Listings"}, {feature: "No Ads on Showcase Listings"}, {feature: "Upload Photos"}, {feature: "Unlimited Categories"}, {feature: "2 Showcase Listings"}]},
    {title: "Professional Platinum", Dollars: "$114.", Cents: "95", term: "/Month", Features: [{feature: "One Time Set Up Fee of $29.95"}, {feature: "10 Searchable Listings"}, {feature: "No Ads on Showcase Listings"}, {feature: "Upload Photos"}, {feature: "Unlimited Categories"}, {feature: "5 Showcase Listings"}]},
  ]
});
```

Inner HTML

```
<template name="pricingItem">
  <div class="pricing-item mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="pricing-title">
      {{title}}
    </div>
  <div class="pricing-value">{{Dollars}}<span class="smallText">{{Cents}}</span>
    <span class="undertext">{{term}}</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="mdl-list list">
    {{#each features}}
      <li class="mdl-list__item">{{feature}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <div class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent mdl-button--raised button">Subscribe</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
{{#each features}}
  <li class="mdl-list__item">{{feature}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

In your data it's:

```
Features: [...]
```

So it's a typo.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, sometimes the code just starts swimming around and I miss stupid stuff like that